# Ajuda com um DropDownlist

Tags: c#, html

Estou com dificuldade em gravar o valor das minha dropdownlist no banco. Quando faço debugger percebo que esta gravando os valores do Id e não dos item selecionados. Como posso fazer para concertar isso.

Essa é minha View:

```
<!--VEICULO-->
<div class="tab-pane" id="VEICULO">
  <div class="row">
    <h4 class="info-text"> Let's start with the basic information (with validation)</h4>

    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Marca do veículo</label> @if (ViewBag.MarcaList != null) { @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.MarcaId, ViewBag.MarcaList as SelectList, "-- Selecione a marca do veículo --", new { @class = "form-control" }) }

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Modelo do veículo</label> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ModeloId, new SelectList(""), "-- Selecione o modelo --", new { @class = "form-control" })
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Versão do veículo</label> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.VersaoId, new SelectList(""), "-- Selecione a versão --", new { @class = "form-control" })

      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Meu controller:

```
 public class ClienteController : Controller
{
    private DBContext db = new DBContext();

    // GET: Cliente
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Clientes.ToList());
    }
    //GET: Enviado
    public ActionResult Enviado()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: Cliente/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Cliente cliente = db.Clientes.Find(id);
        if (cliente == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(cliente);
    }

    // GET: Cliente/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        DBContext sd = new DBContext();
        ViewBag.MarcaList = new SelectList(GetMarcalist(), "MarcaId", "Marca");
        return View();

    }
    public List<MarcaVeiculo> GetMarcalist()
    {
        DBContext sd = new DBContext();
        List<MarcaVeiculo> marcas = sd.marcaVeiculos.ToList();
        return marcas;
    }
    public ActionResult GetmodeloList(int MarcaId)
    {
        DBContext sd = new DBContext();
        List<ModeloVeiculo> selecteList = sd.modeloVeiculos.Where(x => x.MarcaId == MarcaId).ToList();
        ViewBag.modeloList = new SelectList(selecteList, "ModeloId", "Modelo");
        return PartialView("Displaymodelos");
    }


    // POST: Cliente/Create
    // Para se proteger de mais ataques, ative as propriedades específicas a que você quer se conectar. Para 
    // obter mais detalhes, consulte https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Cliente cliente)
    {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
        db.Clientes.Add(cliente);
        db.SaveChanges();

     }
        return Json(new { Resultado = cliente.Id }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        // return View(cliente);
    }

        // GET: Cliente/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Cliente cliente = db.Clientes.Find(id);
        if (cliente == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(cliente);
    }

    // POST: Cliente/Edit/5
    // Para se proteger de mais ataques, ative as propriedades específicas a que você quer se conectar. Para 
    // obter mais detalhes, consulte https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Nome,Email,Telefone")] Cliente cliente)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(cliente).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(cliente);
    }

    // GET: Cliente/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Cliente cliente = db.Clientes.Find(id);
        if (cliente == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(cliente);
    }

    // POST: Cliente/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Cliente cliente = db.Clientes.Find(id);
        db.Clientes.Remove(cliente);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

E o jquery que estou usando pra gravar os dados no DB:

```
function SalvarCliente() {
debugger;

var nome = $("#Nome").val();
var email = $("#Email").val();
var telefone = $("#Telefone").val();

var marca = $("#MarcaId").val();

var modelo = $("#ModeloId").val();
var versao = $("#VersaoId").val();

var residencia = $("#Residencia").val();
var PossuiSeguro = $("#PossuiSeguro").val();

var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
var tokenadr = $('form[action="/Cliente/Create"] input[name="__RequestVerification"]').val();

var headers = {};
var headersadr = {};
headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token;
headersadr['__RequestVerificationToken'] = tokenadr;

var url = "/Cliente/Create";
$.ajax({
    url: url
    , type: "POST"
    , datatype: "json"
    , headers: headersadr
    , data: { Id: 0, Nome: nome, Email: email, Telefone: telefone, MarcaId: marca, ModeloId: modelo, VersaoId: versao, Residencia: residencia, PossuiSeguro: PossuiSeguro, __RequestVerificationToken: token }
    , success: function (data) {
        if (data.Resultado > 0) {



        }
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Entendido! Sou novo no forum e na programação. Por isso deve ter muitos erros no source. Comecei por hobby a 2 semanas. Tenho esse projeto que simula uma cotação de seguro. Tipo Bidu e Minuto. Estava com problemas em 3 dropdownlist em cascading, que me retorna a marca do veiculo, em seguida seu modelo e por ultimo a versão. Estou gravando os dados no banco de dados por um Jquery. Mas o problema era que nessas dropdownlist retornava seus respectivos Id (MarcaId, ModeloId e VersaoId) e não o valor selecionado. Mudei então na Jquery, que por exemplo estava var MarcaId = $("#MarcaId").val(); Coloq

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar as tabelas são construídas através do EntityFramework (code first).

Comment: Não entendi, você quer gravar o nome da marca no banco e não o id dela, que seria de fato a sua chave de referência?

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver assim:

Mudei o `.val()`, para `(option:selected).text();`

Comment: Tudo bem que o código é seu e talz, mas você poderia ser mais específico... Qual `.val()` você alterou? Sempre lembre-se de que no futuro alguém pode ter a mesma dúvida e sua resposta pode ser útil! ;)